# openai-typescript generates strange stuff instead of types

Tags: typescript, express, swagger, openapi

Hi I have yaml like below but instead of generating simple pure interfaces/types it generates some unusual code.

My run command:

> openapi-typescript http://localhost:4201/schema/swagger.yml -o ./src/api/types.ts

what it generates:

```
  "/me": {
    /** Zwraca informacje o zalogowanym użytkowniku */
    get: {
      responses: {
        /** @description Informacje o użytkowniku */
        200: {
          content: {
            "application/json": {
              /** @example abc123 */
              id?: string;
              /** @example jan_kowalski */
              username?: string;
            };
          };
        };
        /** @description User unauthorized */
        401: {
          content: {
            "application/json": components["schemas"]["Unauthorized"];
          };
        };
        /** @description Could not get current user */
        500: {
          content: {
            "application/json": components["schemas"]["GetMeError"];
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

yml:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Moje API
  description: Opis mojego API
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:4201/
paths:
   /me:
    get:
      tags:
        - User
      summary: Zwraca informacje o zalogowanym użytkowniku
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Informacje o użytkowniku
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: string
                    example: abc123
                  username:
                    type: string
                    example: jan_kowalski
        '401':
          description: User unauthorized
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Unauthorized'
        '500':
          description: Could not get current user
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetMeError'
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []
```

I would expect types like this to be generated instead:

```
User: { id: number; username: string }
```